# how to format a date in delphi

Tags: oracle, delphi

How should I write the following select in delphi:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss) from dual
```

When I try to execute it I receive an error, but this works:

```
select to_char(sysdate) from dual
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of making people guess, why don't you include **what error** you receive? Edit your question to add that detail.

Answer (score 3):

Missing single quote possibly at the end of your format string?

```
                                            *
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss') from dual 
                                            *
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try going in to SQL*Plus and running the query that works so you can see what format Delphi seems to want.

Share and enjoy.